# How to include more than 1 string in a if statement

Tags: c#

I have the following and it's not working. I would like to include more than one tag in this if statement. I just started learning c# and would really appreciate some help.

```
if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "test" && "craft")
```

Comment: `if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "test" && hit.collider.gameObject.tag =="craft")`

Comment: @bansi `||` must surely be what the OP wants!

Comment: It does not work because "&& "craft"" is not a condition. You should make a compare with "craft" (ex: variable == "craft") instead.

Comment: if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag.Equals("test") || hit.collider.gameObject.tag.Equals("craft"))
            {
                //Your logic here
            }
Use the Logical OR operator, ||. If the first statement is evaluated to true, the second will not be tested

Comment: @KenY-N looks like yes. Just answered the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No it wont work that way
use 
if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "test" &&  hit.collider.gameObject.tag =="craft")

Comment: `||` must surely be what the OP wants - that will always be `false` barring a bizarre operator overload.

Comment: yeah it was || i wanted but all working well now thanks alot lads

Answer (score -2):

If (var1 == "string1" && var2 == "string2")

Comment: `||` must surely be what the OP wants - that will always be `false` barring a bizarre operator overload.

Comment: Thank and excuse my insomnia.